# Binary classification: positive and negative event

Tags: classification

Let's consider a binary supervised classification problem. Be "A" and "B" the two classes. Sometimes it is said that it if an individual belongs to one of the two classes, we have a "positive event" while if he belongs to the other class we have a "negative event". I know that what is a "positive event" and what is a "negative event" depends on the specific problem but I don't understand how to recognize them. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by recognizing them? positive and negative are just two names you give to the classes. You can name them plus and minus or zero and one.

Answer (score 2):

As you've said it depends on the problem's definition. So, if you read a paper it has to be stated somewhere what the positive class is. Maybe read up on how a *confusion matrix* is build and try out the R-function `confusionMatrix` that comes with the caret package. Said function lets you define what the positive class is and you can see how the evaluation measures change.

```
library(caret)

lvs <- c("normal", "abnormal")
truth <- factor(rep(lvs, times = c(86, 258)),
                levels = rev(lvs))
pred <- factor(
  c(
    rep(lvs, times = c(54, 32)),
    rep(lvs, times = c(27, 231))),               
  levels = rev(lvs))

xtab <- table(pred, truth)

confusionMatrix(xtab, positive = "abnormal")
```